# Haskell: how to read values from stdin line-by-line and add them to a map?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, stdin

I want to read strings from stdin and store them into a map, where `key` is the input string and `value` is the number of previous occurrences of this string. In Java I would have done something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!map.containsKey(input)) {
        map.put(input, 0);
        System.out.println(input);
    } else {
        int num = map.get(input) + 1;
        map.remove(input);
        map.put(input, num);
        System.out.println(input.concat(String.valueOf(num));
    }
}
```

I've tried doing the same in Haskell by using `forM_` but had no luck.

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe

main = do
    input <- getLine
    let n = read input :: Int
    let dataset = Map.empty
    forM_ [1..n] (\i -> do
        input <- getLine
        let a = Map.lookup input dataset
        let dataset' = 
            if isNothing a then
                Map.insert input 0 dataset
            else
                Map.insert input num (Map.delete input dataset)
                where num = ((read (fromJust a) :: Int) + 1)
        let dataset = dataset'
        let output = if isNothing a then
                input
            else
                input ++ fromJust a
        putStrLn output)
```

The contents of `dataset` in the above code does not change at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Map` defined in `Data.Map` is an immutable data type.  Calling `Map.insert` returns a modified `Map`, it does not change the one you already have.  What you want to do is iteratively apply updates in a loop.  Something more like

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (Map)


-- Adds one to an existing value, or sets it to 0 if it isn't present
updateMap :: Map String Int -> String -> Map String Int
updateMap dataset str = M.insertWith updater str 0 dataset
    where
        updater _ 0 = 1
        updater _ old = old + 1

-- Loops n times, returning the final data set when n == 0
loop :: Int -> Map String Int -> IO (Map String Int)
loop 0 dataset = return dataset
loop n dataset = do
    str <- getLine
    let newSet = updateMap dataset str
    loop (n - 1) newSet -- recursively pass in the new map

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- fmap read getLine :: IO Int -- Combine operations into one
    dataset <- loop n M.empty -- Start with an empty map
    print dataset
```

Notice how this is actually less code (it's be even shorter if you just counted the number of occurrences, then `updateMap dataset str = M.insertWith (+) str 1 dataset`), and it separates the pure code from the impure.

In this case, you don't actually want to use `forM_`, because each step of the computation depends on the previous.  It's preferred to write a recursive function that exits at a condition.  If you so desired, you could also write `loop` as

```
loop :: Int -> IO (Map String Int)
loop n = go n M.empty
    where
        go 0 dataset = return dataset
        go n dataset = getLine >>= go (n - 1) . updateMap dataset
```

Here I've compressed the body of the old `loop` into a single line and then put it inside `go`, this allows you to call it as

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- fmap read getLine :: IO Int
    dataset <- loop n
    print dataset
```

This removes the need to know that you must pass in `M.empty` into `loop` for the first call, unless you have a use case to call `loop` multiple times on the same map.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensive explanation! I have only one question about your code: how does value increment work? As far as I understand, it will always return `1` if the same string is encountered more than once.

Comment: @AshtonHearts You are correct, it appears that I made a mistake that I didn't catch with enough testing.  It looks like I got my order of arguments in updater wrong.  I'll fix it

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that `Map.insert` does not do what `map.remove` does in C++.  `Map.insert` returns a new Map which has the element in it but you are simply throwing this new Map away.  This is how nearly all Haskell data structures work, for instance the code:

```
main = do
  let x = []
      y = 5 : x
  print x
```

prints the empty list `[]`.  The cons `:` operator does not destructively modify the empty list but returns a new list containing `5`.  `Map.insert` does the same but with Maps instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

First regarding your java code, you do not need to remove from the map before inserting a new value.

Regarding haskell, the language does not work the way you think it does : your let trick is not updating a value, everything is basically immutable in haskell.

Using only the basic getLine, one way to do it is to use recursion:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map


type Dict = Map.Map String Int

makeDict ::Dict -> Int -> IO Dict
makeDict d remain = if remain == 0 then return d else do
  l <- getLine
  let newd = Map.insertWith (+) l 1 d
  makeDict newd (remain - 1)

newDict count = makeDict Map.empty count
```